# glDrawArrays - guaranteed to copy?

Tags: opengl-es

Following scenario:

I have a buffer of vertices in system memory whose address I submit to glDrawArrays via glVertexAttribPointer every frame. The rendering API is OpenGL ES 3.0.

Now my question:

Can I assume, that glDrawArrays will create a full copy of the buffer on every draw call? Or is it possible that it will draw from the buffer directly if I'm on a shared memory platform?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For all porpoises you need to treat it as "that it will draw from the buffer directly".

When setting the pointer you do not tell the openGL about any sizes of the buffer so at that point there is nothing set at all but some pointer on the GPU or rather an integer value since the same procedure is used when using GPU vertex buffers.

So the data size is only determined when calling draw where you say how many vertices are used from the buffer. At this point I would not expect openGL to copy the data into its internal memory but even if it does it is more like a temporary data cache, nothing more. These data are not reused through render calls and access to data must be done again.

You need to persist the data in your memory and they must be accessible. If they are no longer owned you may make the draw call to draw garbage or even receive a crash if you have no access to the memory you inserted. So for instance setting a pointer from a method/function which allocates the data in stack is generally a no-no.

Comment: "You need to persist the data"; not really - for OpenGL the driver will guarantee that it holds a reference on the data until the draw call has completed. Nothing the application does should force a crash or incorrect render, except specifying more vertices than the buffer contains (which might crash or render garbage due to buffer overrun).

Comment: @solidpixel Talking between setting the buffer pointer and calling to draw. glVertexAttribPointer to glDrawArrays. The first call may not retain and will not retain the data stored at that location. When using shared memory this is extremely important. And yes, it will crash it as the data there may be modified, buffers resized, memory no longer owned...

Comment: True, the reference is only taken when glDraw* is called, but the question did ask about whether glDraw takes a copy, which it does (at least a reference) ...

Comment: @solidpixel I agree the question might be a bit ambiguous but it does mention the 2 calls and shared memory. As for the copy; "it takes a copy" might still be unclear. Assume you are drawing 10000 triangles which may take a significant amount of time. Do you expect it will copy all the data before starting to draw or will it copy the data as it goes? If it copies them as it goes then the issue persists. If another thread might modify the data in the buffer then the drawing is corrupt.

Comment: See previous answer - the driver will guarantee consistency (OpenGL ES is single threaded anyway - you can't really have concurrent use of the same context).

Comment: @solidpixel Are you sure you are not misinterpreting the post you linked? The context operations are synchronized which mean they will execute in the same order in which the instructions were given. In most cases the instruction will even block the thread to ensure correctness but this will not block other threads. So there is no way to prevent other CPU threads to modify the same chunk of memory while openGL is copying that data. That being said even if the draw call does copy the whole buffer and blocks the thread it does not ensure other threads are not modifying the same buffer async.

Comment: Yes, very sure, I wrote it ;P

Comment: In general a CPU thread can modify arbitrary memory - sure - but that's not really what the OP was asking. If you are worrying about CPU threads doing something stupid with memory mapping and making concurrent modifications to arbitrary process memory, then sure, yes it's possible. But at that point all bets are off, and you're lucky your process doesn't just crash.

Comment: For OpenGL ES in general you are talking about a single render thread, due to how the context binding works, so it feels like you are somewhat arguing a corner case of the behaviour rather than what a real application would experience.

Comment: @solidpixel I assume we are talking about a corner case. If we are not then the question is pointless as it makes no difference; "Can I assume, that glDrawArrays will create a full copy of the buffer on every draw call? Or is it possible that it will draw from the buffer directly". Assume the sequence malloc -> setAttributePointer -> free -> draw. This will most likely work in most situations but may fail depending on the what the system does in the background. You can get bad access and you can get garbage. Same happens when returning memory from stack setAttributePointer(..., getPointer()...

Comment: Why do you need to have two threads? The question makes perfect sense if you consider one thread doing glBufferSubData() / glDraw() / glBufferSubData() / glDraw() using the same buffer for each draw. If you know rendering is asynchronous, knowing whether the buffer data is copied or not is really important to know ...

Comment: @solidpixel this has nothing to do with buffers. There is no glBufferSubData(). We are talking about the direct access to the CPU memory. In this case no buffer is bound and we are talking about shared memory. It is quite common to use this on mobile devices. So for instance freed memory may be very hard to debug as it may be valid for relatively long time until you will start seeing garbage or get a crash. But you can understand that any module, any part, any thread may access that memory.

Comment: Rendering *never* uses application memory directly. As far as I can tell the only reason to care about copies during a glDraw() relates to GPU rendering stability. So you can argue its not about buffers, but I think you're wrong - that's the only reason to care ...

Comment: @solidpixel Rendering itself does not but going step backwards when using shared memory where you have no buffers on GPU and again use SHARED memory: the procedure must be to either access the memory on the CPU when needed (per vertex or per shape) or copy all of it at once (which seems like having GPU buffers implicitly). Neither of the cases guaranty that when accessing the CPU buffer this access is safe and the data is consistent no matter what. As long as the CPU part is multithreaded bad things can happen and openGL CAN NOT guarantee correct behavior.

Comment: For client-side buffers the spec requires that glDraw() takes a copy. The application is allowed to free or otherwise arbitrarily corrupt the client-side memory after the glDraw has occurred.

From the GL / GL ES spec point of view, there is no such thing as shared memory - that's purely in an implementation detail on systems without dedicated graphics RAM.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I assume, that glDrawArrays will create a full copy of the buffer
>   on every draw call?

Graphics drivers try very hard not to copy bulk data buffers - it's horribly slow and energy intensive. The entire point of using buffers rather than client-side arrays is that they can be uploaded to the graphics server once and subsequently just referenced by the draw call without needing a copy or (on desktop) a transfer over PCIe into graphics RAM.

Rendering will behave as if the buffer has been copied (e.g. the output must reflect the state of the buffer at the point the draw call was made, even if it is subsequently modified). However, in most cases no copy is actually needed.

A badly written application can force copies to be taken; for example, if you modify a buffer (e.g. calling `glBufferSubData`) immediately after submitting a draw using it, the driver may need to create a new version of the buffer as the original data is likely still referenced by the draw you just queued. Well written applications try to pipeline their resource updates so this doesn't happen because it is normally fatal for application rendering performance ...

See https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-6-efficiently-updating-dynamic-resources for a longer explanation.